# Python: \b behaves differently from book's description

Tags: python

I'm reading *automate_the_boring_stuff_with_python_2015* and I got to this snippet:

```
print(positionStr, end='')
print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
```

where positionStr is a string defined earlier. I looked at python escape sequences and saw that \b is backspace but for some reason the author says it should erase the printed string

> To erase text, print the \b backspace escape character. This special
>   character erases a character at the end of the current line on the screen. The line at u uses string replication to produce a string with as many \b
>   characters as the length of the string stored in positionStr, which has the
>   effect of erasing the positionStr string that was last printed.

1. this contradicts what I saw in [here](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html) (table in mid page)
2. this differs from my results [image]

As you can see I got a bunch of backspace chars, as I guess I should have (I ran a loop in which I printed the said string and then the `\b` string)

Now, is the book wrong or should I have done something different in order for it to work? Additionally, if this is wrong, is there a way to achieve this goal? (print string and then delete it)

*As it can be seen from the picture, I work with python 3.5.3. on Windows 8.1*

Comment: In the future, please search Google before posting a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all consoles support the `\b` character as a deletion character, especially graphical ones.

(same thing happens when you write it to a file, the previous char is not deleted either)

Try your example in a native shell (Windows or Linux would work) and the characters will be properly deleted.

Windows CMD:

```
>>> print("a\bc")
c
```

PyScripter (that's what I have):

```
>>> print("a\bc")
a<strange char>c
```

Comment: Not much need to answer such a common duplicate.